# tracking-pixel known list

Tags: google-tag-manager, tracking-pixel

i'm looking for a database/list of common tracking pixels providers / domains  (especially those which comes from GTM) for example:

```
 - cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel
 - http://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect
 - adroll.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is focusing on tracking pixels in web browsers; you didn't specify.

To block remote resources  **in email messages** (img, embed, a, link, etc...) I've been using little snitch: https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

I like images in my emails so I wanted to block remote resources that caused no visible change in my messages. If a blocked domain caused a visible change in my email I removed the domain blocking rule.

Here is a list of the domains that I've caught so far with my *4 day old pixel tracking domain harvesting experiment*.

**IMPORTANT**: This list is letting visible remote resources through that can still be used for tracking* but it's been fun to have a false sense of security from tracking pixels anyway.

**Here are the goods:**

```
force.com                       port 443 (https)
my.salesforce.com               port 80   (http)
ib.anycast.adnxs.com            port 80   (http)
responsys.hs.llnwd.net          port 443 (https)
ink1001.com                     port 80   (http)
tag.yieldoptimizer.com          port 443 (https)
dge9rmgqjs8m1.cloudfront.net    port 443 (https)
a5.mzstatic.com                 port 80   (http)
a2.mzstatic.com                 port 80   (http)
t.sigopn03.com                  port 80   (http)
log.dmtry.com                   port 80   (http)
t.email.vistaprint.com          port 80   (http)
click.icptrack.com              port 80   (http)
staticapp.icpsc.com             port 443 (https)
em.autopilotmail.io             port 80   (http)
c940564.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com     port 443 (https)
r20.rs6.net                     port 80   (http)
contentz.mkt3422.com            port 80   (http)
f0.bcbits.com                   port 80   (http)
static.cdn.responsys.net        port 80   (http)
t.signauxdeux.com               port 80   (http)
trk.kissmetrics.com             port 80   (http)
click.kiuwan.com                port 80   (http)
via.intercom.io                 port 443 (https)
marketing.intercomassets.com    port 443 (https)
```

Good luck!

*Any remote html resource could be used for 3rd party tracking purposes. Like:

```
<a src="*" />
<embed src="*" /> 
<script src="*" /> 
<link href="*" />
```

Edit: code formatting